# Execution of nnoremap takes significant time

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I am developing a vim plugin and I have set a default mapping this way.

```
if !hasmapto('<Plug>DumpDebugString')
    nmap <unique> <Leader>ds  <Plug>DumpDebugString
    nmap <unique> <Leader>dS  <Plug>DumpDebugStringExpr
endif

...

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>DumpDebugString :<C-U> :call <SID>debugFunctionWrapper(0)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>DumpDebugStringExpr :<C-U> :call <SID>debugFunctionWrapper(1)<CR>
```

When I try invoking ds the DumpDebugString method runs correctly but takes some time actually get called in the first place. It is run instantly only if I map it like this:

```
nmap <leader>ds <Plug>DumpDebugString<CR>
```

But the extra `<CR>` shouldn't be needed since it already included in the `nnoremap` call.

- I don't think it has anything to do with the actual mapping characters or with the use of `<Plug>`.
- Substituting `:call <SID>debugFunctionWrapper(0)<CR>` with something like `:call str2nr("1")<CR>` doesn't seem to solve the problem
- Adding `<nowait>` doesn't do anything.

For the story, here's the plugin: https://github.com/bergercookie/vim-debugstring

Comment: You can simply your `:call`'s to just `:<c-u>call` instead of `:<c-u> :call`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you press `Leader d s`, Vim expands the keysequence into `<plug>DumpDebugString`.
However, it doesn't expand the latter immediately, because it waits for you to maybe press `Expr` afterwards.
This is due to the other `<plug>` mapping:

```
nmap <nowait> <unique> <Leader>dS  <Plug>DumpDebugStringExpr
                                                        ^^^^
                                                        Vim waits `&ttimeout` ms for these keys to be typed
```

One solution is to surround all your `<plug>` mappings with parentheses:

```
nmap <unique> <Leader>ds  <Plug>(DumpDebugString)
nmap <unique> <Leader>dS  <Plug>(DumpDebugStringExpr)
```

Now, when you press `Leader d s`, and it gets expanded into `<plug>(DumpDebugString)`, there's no ambiguity anymore.
Vim doesn't wait for `Expr` to be typed because there's no `<plug>(DumpDebugString)Expr` mapping.

Comment: Yeah, that's right!
I should have guessed! I resided into changing the DumpDebugString to a different name in the first place as I find it to be more clean but the root cause is the same nonetheless.